# SQL not hard case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on an issue with a stored procedure.  I have the following:

```
SELECT @message = 'ID' + CAST(CASE WHEN @StoreID = 0 THEN 'BK' 
                                   WHEN @StoreID = 1 THEN 'MK'
                                        END AS VARCHAR (50)) + char(13)
```

This sends an e-mail that says: `ID: 'MK'` or `ID:'BK'`.

Currently i'm hard-coding the case statement, but I need to pull the strings '`BK`' '`MK`' from a different table all together.

The `@StoreID` is from the `Store_Orders` table.  The names are from the Store table.

One way to get this I tried was doing this:

```
SELECT @message = 'ID' + StoreName from db.Store where StoreName = StoreID and StoreID = @StoreID
```

When I execute the code, it finds the correct store, but says that

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MK' to data type
>   int.

But I don't want to convert 'MK' I want to display 'MK' by finding it via the @StoreID.

Comment: The code makes little sense, and even less with a MySQL tag.  What database are you really using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: its a simple case statement, if storeId is 0 then display following string, but i need to fetch it from the db table instead of hard-coding it

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ID: ' , CASE WHEN s.StoreID = 0 
THEN (select '(''' + colname + ''')' 
  from othertable ot where ot.colname = s.colname) 
WHEN s.StoreID = 1 
THEN (select '(''' + colname + ''')' 
  from othertable ot where ot.colname = s.colname)
END) AS 'Message'
FROM Store_Orders s
```

Comment: I need to basically convert the ID to its "name" but I can't hard-code the case statement, it needs to pull from the table whatever the ID is - so that as we add more ID's we don't have to manually enter 'BK3' or 'MMK'.

Comment: I have provided a sample code where you can insert your table names and column names according to your requirement. Or you can update your question with DDL of the other table that has those codes and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: i basically need to figure out how to get the: NAME from stores where storename = storeid and storeid = StoreID  ... but its not converting because storeID is int and storename is varchar